# update array in mongoose which matches the condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my schema looks like

```
{
    qty:{
        property1:{
            //something
        }
        property2:[{
            size:40,
            color:"black",
            enabled:"true"
        }]
    }
}
```

property 2 is array what i want to do is update those array object whose enabled is true in single query

I tried writing the following query

```
    db.col.update({
    "qty.property2.enabled" = "true"
}, {
    "qty.property2.color" = "green"
}, callback)
```

but it is not working

error:

> [main] Error: can't have . in field names [qty.pro.size]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.col.update({"qty.property2.enabled":"true"},{$set: {'qty.property2.$.color': 'green'}}, {multi: true})
```

this is the way to update element inside array.

1. equal sign '=' cannot be used inside object
2. updating array is done using $

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution for multiple conditions:

```
db.foo.update({
        _id:"i1",
        replies: { $elemMatch:{
            _id: "s2",
            update_password: "abc"
        }}
    },
    {
        "$set" : {"replies.$.text" : "blah"}
    }
);
```

**Why**

So I was looking for similar solution as this question, but in my case I needed array element to match multiple conditions and using currently provided answers resulted in changes to wrong fields.

If you need to match multiple fields, for example let say we have element like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("i1"),
    "replies": [
         {
          "_id" : ObjectId("s1"),
          "update_password": "abc",
          "text": "some stuff"
         },
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("s2"),
            "update_password": "abc",
            "text": "some stuff"
         }    
    ]
}
```

Trying to do update by

```
db.foo.update({
        _id:"i1",
        "replies._id":"s2",
        "replies.update_password": "abc"
    },
    {
        "$set" : {"replies.$.text" : "blah"}
    }
);
```

Would result in updating to field that only matches one condition, for example it would update s1 because it matches update_password condition, which is clearly wrong. I might have did something wrong, but $elemMatch solution solved any problems like that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your documet looks like this.

```
{

   "_id" : ObjectId("4f9808648859c65d"),

   "array" : [

       {"text" : "foo", "value" : 11},

       {"text" : "foo", "value" : 22},

       {"text" : "foobar", "value" : 33}

   ]

}
```

then your query will be

```
db.foo.update({"array.value" : 22}, {"$set" : {"array.$.text" : "blah"}})
```

where first curly brackets represents query criteria and second one sets the new value.